# Extract everything from PDF

Tags: pdf, text, image, extract

Looking for solution to extract content from a PDF file (using console tool or a library).

It will be used on server to produce on-line e-books from uploaded PDF files.

Need to extract following things:

1. text with fonts and styles;
2. images;
3. audio and video;
4. links and hotspots.
5. page snapshots and thumbnails;
6. general PDF information, e.g. book layouts, number of pages etc.

Looking at Adobe PDF Library ($5000 though), BCL SDK (?), PDFLib (€795), QuickPDF ($250)

Now we are using open source pdf2xml (extracts text, images and links) and GhostScript (snapshots and thumbnails). The other things left are:

1. fonts;
2. multimedia;
3. hotspots;
4. page info.

We are hesitating between paying a lot of money (and possibly make mistake choosing wrong solution) or use free/open source solutions.

Which BEST solution to extract nearly everything from PDF would you recommend?

Any comments will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like with a few days or weeks effort, you can adapt the open source tools to your needs. Fonts and everything can certainly be extracted, this is something that every PDF reader must do anyway to display them.

You should probably take an estimate of programmer costs ($/hr) and multiply it by the estimated time it would take to add the needed open source functionality (60-80 hours?). If this is greater or close to $5000 anyway, you might consider just buying the commercial software.

Otherwise, with the help of the (quite good) [PDF reference](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html), you should be well on your way.

One more thing, you might find [Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) to be of help. It is for rendering PDF, but that is very related to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Difficulty here is that even commercial SDK will require programming efforts. At their features' summary everything look great, however looking in samples, it's still unclear how to extract for example video to external file, they just dump annotation information (talking about PDFlib pCOS).

Comment: Yeah, you'd have to factor that in to the cost.

Answer (score 1):

A: Font: I dont think fonts can be extracted.

B: Not sure about multimedia

C: What are hotspots?

D: Have a look at iTextSharp (open source), you might be able to extract more page info.

Comment: > A: Font: I dont think fonts can be extracted.
We need proper font names at least to use system fonts.

> B: Not sure about multimedia
Multimedia are in annotations objects in PDF as I know, so solution should be able to iterate through them in the pdf to extract right?

> C: What are hotspots?
Hotspot is a kind of rectangular link for example on a part of image.

> Have a look at iTextSharp (open source), you might be able to extract more page info.
Thank you, will give it a try.

Comment: It seems to me that iText is for generating pdf files not for extracting their content. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes its is mostly for generating PDF files, just thought you might be able to extract some info, like number of pages, page sizes and possibly page info? Also have a look at http://www.tallcomponents.com/ they have some decent tools too.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [PDF Suite](http://bytescout.com/products/developer/pdfsuite/index.html) that contains 3 SDKs especially designed to extract content from PDF, render PDF as image and convert to html. Though no font files extraction but it supports XML output and text extraction preserving the original layout.

There is a ["PDF Multitool"](http://bytescout.com/products/pdfmultitool/index.html) free utility that is based on this engine so you play with it to see how it works for PDF files you have.

Disclaimer: I work for ByteScout

Comment: Can it be used to extract video files from PDFs that have them? How?

Comment: it is in the work already for the next version, it will be able to extract video too

Comment: I had emailed your company's tech support and did not hear back. Please let us know when Video extraction is added to the PDF Multi-tool Free Utility.

Comment: @alexs check if you got the notification after the request, all tickets there are processed by techsupport panel with auto email notifications about status update (ticket received, pending, on hold, solved etc)

Comment: Yes. I got one update that said they forwarded it on and I should expect a response in X days. Nothing yet.

Comment: @AlexS please check your email for the updated version with video support

Comment: Eugene - Updated version is there now on website or in my email only?

Comment: Eugene, 

The whole discussion here & on StackExchange has been about "PDF Multi tool", not about programming using an SDK. 

I'd like to use PDF Multi tool (as suggested on your SE Answer) to extract videos, just the same way it allows extraction of other things. 

If PDF Multi tool is not updated for video extraction then it is incomplete as a sample solution and we cant test it. 

Thanks, 

- A

Comment: @AlexS oh, sure, free ByteScout PDF Multitool 6.20.2354 and later was also updated just a few days on the web-site, it is able extract video and audio (use Data Extraction - Embedded Multimedia in the menu). You may download it from  https://bytescout.com/products/pdfmultitool/index.html

Comment: Tested it. Better. But, it does not allow individual extraction of video but Bulk/ batch. And when it does that, it renames all original embedded videos as Video1.avi, Video2.avi etc... Can you add an option to let original media file name {inside PDF} - Originals were Name.mp4, AnotherName.FLV etc.

Comment: Also, being able to select & extract videos from pages in Multi tool will make sense.

Comment: @AlexS thank you for suggestions! will log these requests to implement in next versions of the utility!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can extract the texts, text style information, images, link annotations, bookmarks and even you can get the paragraph id information, except the tables.
Check this link.

http://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/index.html

It really works fine.

Comment: @MS - What about Videos?

Answer (score 0):

tika http://tika.apache.org/ Its advantage is to extract text from multi types. but it can solve your problem as well.

For the implementation:
The goal of Tika is to reuse existing parser libraries like PDFBox or Apache POI as much as possible, and so most of the parser classes in Tika are adapters to such external libraries.

I think tika may work as you describe. Extract things with categeries. (Will add more code later.)

---

Not an exact answer yet.